# How to pass extra data to activity from homescreen shortcut?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-shortcut

I have an Non-Launcher activity with a context menu. The menu contains an option to add the activity to android home screen as a shortcut.

I am using the below code to create the shortcut.

```
private void ShortcutIcon(){

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Test");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Necessary permissions and intent filters are correctly set. When I run this code, the shortcut is created successfully. On shortcut click, the activity opens as expected.

However, my activity shows some dynamic data. for that I need to pass one small string variable to the activity.

I have tried to use this code before `setAction` (just like you would pass extra data to a normal intent for launching an activity)

```
addIntent.putExtra("key_primarykey", value_i_want_to_pass);
```

However, when user clicks on the shortcut, inside the activity, the `value_i_want_to_pass` comes as Null.

Some applications like `Whatsapp` allows to do exactly the same. you can save a shortcut of a chat. also some `dialer apps` allow to add a contact as a shortcut so that when you tap on the shortcut, a voice call is initiated automatically.

I want to know how can I pass some data from my shortcut to my activity.

Comment: Same scenario for me as well. Do you have any inputs ?

Comment: No I still could not make it work. Also could not find a working solution all over internet.

Comment: @KarthikeyanP check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your data to `addIntent` which will be caught by Launcher's Broadcast Receiver.

Just change following line

```
addIntent.putExtra("key_primarykey", value_i_want_to_pass);
```

to

```
shortcutIntent.putExtra("key_primarykey", value_i_want_to_pass);
```

and write it along with your `shorcutIntent` code before setting `shortcutIntent` to `addIntent`.
So that the `Action Intent` you are setting for the shortcut will return you the correct value.
So the modified code will be as follows.

```
private void ShortcutIcon(){

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("key_primarykey", value_i_want_to_pass);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Test");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Comment: same result dude, just null